# Timezone mismatch in MeteorJS and MomentJS insert and find

Tags: javascript, date, meteor, momentjs

I'm adding dates to a Meteor Collection called Meals. The date is the date of the meal and it's showing the previous day as the date of the meal when I refresh the publication. The meals are added in a Meteor.method including this:

```
        // pick out the whitelisted keys
    var item = {
        name  : postAttributes.name,
        date : moment(postAttributes.date).utc().toDate(),
        userId: user._id, 
        author: user.emails[0].address, 
        created: moment().toDate()
    };

    console.log(item.date)

    var nameId = Meals.insert(item);
    var meal = Meals.findOne(nameId);
    console.log(meal)
```

console.log(item.date) returns

```
Fri Nov 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
```

console.log(meal) returns

```
_id: "vyrXkmRFsD5px7wFz"
author: "ellis.cs@gmail.com"
created: Sun Oct 25 2015 21:02:26 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
date: Fri Nov 06 2015 00:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
name: "Tacos"
userId: "kyd9dMb9iCuRJTMhW"
```

However, if I immediately do a

```
Meals.find({name : "Tacos}).fetch();
```

It returns

```
_id: "vyrXkmRFsD5px7wFz"
author: "ellis.cs@gmail.com"
created: Sun Oct 25 2015 21:02:25 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
date: Thu Nov 05 2015 19:00:00 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)
name: "Tacos"
userId: "kyd9dMb9iCuRJTMhW"
```

Note the difference in date field. I'm at a loss here.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 notes:

1. moment().utc().toDate(): actually returns the native Date object using by MomentJs itself, which is a local datetime. You can check it by the following code:

   ```
   var now = moment().utc();
   var localDateTime = now .toDate();
   var utcDateTime= now.toString();

   console.log(localDateTime);
   console.log(utcDateTime);
   ```
2. The BSON Date data type that MongoDB uses is simply a 64-bit integer count of milliseconds since UTC Jan 1, 1970. So the the actual value stored is a UTC one. But when you print it in the browser console, it backs to the local datetime again

Comment: Using toString() fixes the problem of the dates changing, but if I save in Meteor as a string, I lose the ability to filter out by date. My publication depends on only displaying dates within a certain range.